# Concurrent Windows Services that monitors directory changes

Tags: c#

Is there any .Net Windows service library that monitors directory changes? I am doing a file transfer application, so as soon as a new file/ folder is added to the monitored directory, I will execute my c# code to other some other operations.

The monitoring should fire my service as soon as new folder/file is added, which means that one multiple instance of my service can run at the same time. What is the best/ established techniques to handle these scenario? I am pretty sure there is a standard term for this but I don't know about it.

Answer (score 3):

Look at: [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)